# My new migration will brake my database on the heroku (postgres)

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

I am facing a challenge here. So I inhertied the models from previous developers and the tables were not properly built. I added some constraints and new tables in order to normalize those tables. Before pushing the application to the heroku I tested it on my local machine and it actually broke my database.

Now the heroku website is already in production, so there are user information. How should i approach this, do I need to destroy the existing database and create a new one and run the migrations

Comment: It's important to take care when writing migrations that you write them such that they _don't_ break your database. If that is impossible you'll have to figure out your own strategy. We don't know anything about your business requirements, your application, your database structure, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Be very, very careful. Applying migrations on production servers can cause irreversible damage if you are not careful, and so you should be prepared for *every* possible situation.

My best recommendation would be to create an entire duplicate copy of your live DB (using Heroku this is as simple as a PG dump/backup). You can then create a new staging site using the same code, upload the backup into a new Database instance, and then test against that. Live environments *are not* always the same as local ones. You can then run your migrations on the staging site, and see if there are any unexpected effects (the best way to do this would be by utilizing django test cases). If there are any issues, be sure to understand how the rollback process works with django migrations.

A good tutorial that is fairly recent can be found here: https://realpython.com/django-migrations-a-primer/